# Half or full dead trees after the last winter. How can I "fix" the half dead ones?

Tags: diagnosis

Not sure what caused this disaster but we noticed this in the spring. I have not done anything yet because I was hopping some of the branches might come back.
I was told it was a fungus but I am not sure since it is not progressing
Most of the below pictures are from my backyard, excepting the big tree above the roof ..that is in on adjacent property. I have three potted Euonymous plants like the one you see below, all killed

Freeze/mild winter followed by sudden temp drop is the other thing that I suspect it might caused this. It also selectively killed only one species of the ornamental grasses that I have in my backyard, see the last picture, marked with red arrows

[image]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/3vy5Bxc.jpeg]
[image: https://i.imgur.com/UC64tPh.png]
[image]
[image]

Update: I am in Toronto
The small tree has-been there for 5 6 years, Jaina Japanese Maple tree. The other one is a Golden Hart Red Bud

Comment: We do not know your USDA zone. I think the damages are unusual for late freezes. It look likes a Japanese Acer and perhaps a Davidia involucrata. Both hardy trees. None of your photos has a clear indication of any fungus. Consider it could be something in the soil too including a poorly mixed fertilizer.

Comment: See the update please

Comment: Which part of Canada do you live in?

Comment: I live in Toronto

Answer (score 2):

No magic here. Options:

Cut off the dead parts and wait.

Rip out the whole thing and replace, preferably with something hardier. If you replace with the same thing, anticipate similar damage in similar weather patterns in the future.

Comment: The Japanese Maple has been there for years without a problem. The other one is a cultivar but native to Canada tree https://www.gardenia.net/plant/cercis-canadensis-hearts-of-gold-eastern-redbud  There is more to pruning than you just said. There is no reason to remove the trees if they can be pruned and trained

Answer (score 2):

### Late freeze hypotheses:

Toronto is USDA hardiness zone 6a.

Your Cercis canadensis 'Hearts of Gold' (Eastern Redbud) is native to your region and ["grows well in USDA Hardiness Zones 4-8"](https://thetreestore.info/redbud-tree/).

Most Japanese maples are [hardy in 5-8 and at least 6-8](https://www.japanesemaplesonline.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/home.showpage/pageID/4/index.htm)

The big tree seems to have been exposed to at least 15 winters.

All seems to be well established in a protected place.

Growing an Euonymus in a barrel rather than established in the ground is more risky.
However, e.g. [Euonymus alatus ‘Fire Ball’ is hardy in zone 4-8](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/shrubs/euonymus/euonymus-plant-varieties.htm) so it is not impossible.

The [historical winter temperatures in Toronto 2022](https://weatherspark.com/h/y/19863/2022/Historical-Weather-during-2022-in-Toronto-Canada#Figures-Temperature) are in no way unusual, and this are the coldest temperatures measured in Toronto. A well protected place among houses was probably not as cold as that.

**Conclusion:**

It is highly unlikely that several hardy, protected and well established plants should surrender in a common winter. Let us leave this hypotheses.

### Fungus hypoteses:

The title mentions "dead trees after last winter", but actually I think you first realized something was wrong when new foliage did not appear as expected.
Most fungi are not active during then winther, but they can [appear soon after](http://website.nbm-mnb.ca/mycologywebpages/Checklists/WinterFungi/WinterFungiDiscussion.html):

> The successful species are often those that can release spores as soon as above-freezing temperatures arrive.
> Species such as Cordyceps variabilis, Melampsorella caryophyllacearum or Mycophycias ascophylli do not appear until winter is long gone, because their insect, plant or algal hosts are not receptive until then

I have chosen two common fungi based on the description of the symptoms, but of course we can not rule out many other fungi.

**Verticillium Maple wilt:**

This is a common [fungus](https://www.gotreequotes.com/tree-fungus-identification-and-treatment/#Verticillium_Maple_wilt) which infects multiple hosts including red buds, but monocots (grasses) are not susceptible to this disease.
It originates from the roots, and matches your experience:

> The blockage that the fungus invasion causes typically leads to a number of symptoms. This includes stunted growth, yellowing foliage, and leaves that curl and dry out. **And these symptoms usually appear on one side of the tree.**

(emphasis mine)

It can be a [little tricky](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/verticillium_wilt_refresher) to realize what is going on:

> Sometimes a single branch or the foliage on one side of a tree will die. **Trees can go through years where no symptoms are present and then the symptoms show up again several years later.** Some trees can struggle along for years, while others may die soon after symptoms appear. In addition to wilting, other symptoms may include: small leaves, stunting shoot growth, poor radial growth, sparse foliage and abnormally large seed crops.

(emphasis mine)

To be sure you will need a lab test so save pieces of dead wood:

> Conclusive diagnosis of verticillium requires laboratory culture of the pathogen from symptomatic wood. Other injuries to wood can also cause vascular discoloration. Don’t be too hasty to make the conclusion that verticillium is the cause, because if it isn’t, decisions about management and selection of replacement trees will be quite different. The Plant Disease Diagnostic Lab at Cornell, as well as diagnostic laboratories at other state universities, are able to provide this service - sometimes for a modest fee.

**Phytophthora root rot:**

Attacks Acer, Cercis, Euonymus  and  many other [trees/shrubs](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/pdfs/phytophthora-host-list.pdf).
Perhaps you can identify by the fingerprint of attacked plants.

Root rot is ["primarily a disease of heavy or waterlogged soils"](https://www.rhs.org.uk/disease/phytophthora-root-rot). Perhaps it was not the cold winter but rather the combination of frozen soil and then mild wet weather which caused standing water and/or waterlogged soil which again lead to die back in your trees.

[Typical symptoms](http://gardeninginfo-online.com/phytophthora-root-rot-symptoms-treatment-prevention/) include

> - Blackening of the lower trunk or stem
> - Dieback of shoots and foliage
> - Soft, brown roots instead of firm, white ones

**Try to carefully dig down to the roots of your maple tree at the damaged side to look for indication of root rot.**

**Conclusion:**

Arguments against this hypotheses: Normally damages first appear in May or June.

On the other hand, I do not think we can reject this hypotheses, and you should investigate it further.
If you prune out dead wood, then save smaller pieces in a sealed plastic bag for later analyses.

Comment: Do the above apply to grasses which were like hand picked (see the picture)

Comment: As I wrote grass is not susceptible to maple wilt. Other fungi like root rot and snow rot can easily kill grasses. Most grasses grows well in temperate climate, and low temperatures are usually not a problem. I think ornamental grasses sold i Canada is hardy to at least -10 F.

Comment: Like the other plants that died the grasses have been there for years
I am trying to understand what hit all these plants at the same time

Comment: I agree: This does not look like a coincident.
I did not cover the grasses in my answer because I do not recognize that genus.
I encourage you to examine your dead/ill plants. Perhaps you do not feel qualified for the task, but try anyway. That is how I got started, and how I am still learning every new season.

Answer (score 1):

You may be right about the temperature fluctuation causing the dieback. In my part of the US (zone 5a - min temps between -15 to -20F), we had a recent winter where we went from normal hi/lo of 25F/7F or so to a more "old fashioned" winter of -20F/-2F for a short stretch, followed by a thaw. Mature Japanese maples died back to the ground unless they were in a sheltered (i.e. south-facing and near a house) location. Paperbark maples mostly died back, and even some 10 yo+ tulip trees showed partial winterkill.

As for your trees, I'd prune out the deadwood, as it would've come back by now if it were alive. The trees (especially the redbud) will throw out new growth next year, but be prepared for that new growth to come from the roots, not the trunk. This is what happened the spring following the winter I wrote about above.

If the growth *is* from the roots, I'd probably keep both the pruned old-growth and one stem of the new-growth for 2023, then cut the old-growth out during the winter if 2023-24 to encourage the trees to grow tall and well-shaped. In effect, you'll be keeping the trees but losing years of growth.

Comment: yes it was this event described here https://www.blogto.com/city/2021/12/toronto-broke-heat-record/

Comment: that is the part that puzzles me, how to make the tree grown nice from what is left. even if I let something grow from the root level that would go to the side ..how is that going to grow right ? The redbud was already grafted, it is a cultivar and I think it won't grow from the root

Comment: If a tree sprouts from the roots, it naturally grows straight, but the redbud will probably grow as the species (this may also apply to the Japanese maple as well). In that case, then you don't want to encourage the root-instigated growth, so the best you can do is to prune the dead wood and hope for the best that new growth will result in a terminal leader at some point. Remember, the branches you see on the tree will be pruned off anyway as that tree reaches 7-8 feet tall.

Comment: you can see in the picture that the japanese maple alread sprouted from the left side of that main fork. The redbud is more complicated to prune and to straighten

Comment: I didn't notice the little branch there, but that's great news for the tree. When young, redbuds seem to like to grow in a fan shape if left to their own devices (they tend to develop a leader later in life). Pruning out the deadwood may encourage the tree to sprout more central branches, but at this late date in the year you may want to wait a couple of months so that the new growth (if any) sprouts next spring.